# Building install4j project fails with "/bin/sh failed with return code 1"

Tags: install4j

I am building an install4j project in verbose mode and it sporadically fails with the following generic error at the very end of the build (no other errors are displayed):

```
07:08:29 [install4j] Writing md5sums.
07:08:29 [install4j] Writing output.txt.
07:08:29 [install4j] Writing updates.xml.
07:08:29 [install4j] 
07:08:29 [install4j] Build completed in 126.5 seconds.
07:08:29 
07:08:29 BUILD FAILED
07:08:29 /home/jenkins/workspace/Product-Build/src/build.xml:1736: The following error occurred while executing this line:
07:08:29 /home/jenkins/workspace/Product-Build/src/build.xml:1745: The following error occurred while executing this line:
07:08:29 /home/jenkins/workspace/Product-Build/src/macros.xml:228: /bin/sh failed with return code 1
```

Update: looking through the log I found the following exception which explained the failure:

```
08:43:55 [install4j] com.a.a.d: The path "<PATH>/file" does not exist.
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.b.b.f.a(ejt:241)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.b.b.f.a(ejt:114)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.b.b.f.a(ejt:90)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.b.h.a(ejt:197)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.b.h.d(ejt:106)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.c(ejt:435)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.a.a.a(ejt:286)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:92)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
08:43:55 [install4j]    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
08:43:55 [install4j] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: The path "<PATH>/file" does not exist.
```

Comment: Try to switch on verbose output to check if you can see anything unusual. Is this the current version?

Comment: We are running on: 08:43:30 [install4j] install4j version 5.1.5 (build 5568), built on 2013-01-15.  The verbose flag is turned on but I don't see anything unusual

Comment: Taking another look I missed an exception in the resulting log.  The strange part is that the executable was actually built successfully despite the exception.

Comment: Can you post the exception? I think it should be printed in any case.